# Pseudocode and tens digit

Tags: pseudocode

Good day, I'm a complete newbie and need to solve a problem. I'm not asking someone to do my assignment for me I'm just stuck and If I can see the code I will be able to understand how it was done and create a new problem to check if I understand the solution.

Enter an integer value for the variable called 'num' that contains a value between 35 and 74. Determine if the 'tens' digit is equal to, greater than or less than the 'ones' digit.

I must use pseudo code but cant find anything in my text book.

I dont know how to create an variable with a number between 35 and 75

I know what's a 'tens' and 'ones' digit but have no idea on how to do the calculation.

If someone can please help me with this it will be much appreciated. The book I have is not helpful and I need help.

Thanks in advance

G

Comment: In the number 75, 7 is in the tens digit and 5 is in the ones digit. Similarly, in 534, 5 is at the hundreds digit place. Read up on the modulo operator. It will probably be key to your success. Specifically, modulo by 10 and 100

Comment: What language are you using?